# Can currying be used with lambda functions?

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming, c++11, lambda

This piece of code fails to compile and I don't know if it is because it can not be done, lambdas do not inherit from binary_function, or it is just that I'm getting the syntax wrong

```
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   auto lambda = [](int x, int y) -> int { return x + y; };
   auto sumFive = std::bind1st(lambda, 5); 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use:

```
auto sumFive = std::bind(lambda, 5, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Please forget entirely about `bind1st` and `binary_function`, etc. Those were crutches in the old C++ because of the lack of lambdas and variadic templates. In C++11, use `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: Minor correction: lambdas have nothing to do with the implementation of `std::bind` and ``std::function`` - and variadic templates just make it easier/work for an infinite number of parameters.

Comment: @Itjax: Yes, thanks. I was lumping a couple of things together there. Fact is, in C++11 you can freely bind anything, and in particular lambdas. The other thing I guess is that `std::function` is necessary as a recipient type for lambdas, whose actual type is not known.

Comment: It's very weird to have a type that can't be named.

Comment: @Omni: You can always convert a lambda to a `std::function`, and likewise for bind expressions, and you can even convert non-capturing lambdas to function pointers. If you check the assembly, you might be able to spot the internal type names of your lamdbas :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Oh, I've already done that. *grin* I can't leave that kind of thing alone and unknown..

Answer (score 8):

`std::bind1st` and `std::bind` are redundant in C++11. Just use another lambda:

```
auto lambda = [](int x, int y) { return x + y; };
auto sumFive = [&](int y) { return lambda(5, y); };
```

This is clearer and simpler (no need to know what `std::bind` does or what the `std::placeholders` are for), more flexible (it can support any expression, not just parameter binding), requires no support headers, and will probably compile a little faster too.

Comment: Yes, it works, but this solution is completely against the functional programming paradigm.

Comment: @Cartesius00 why is that?